# How to get the coordinate of a pixel that is containing right hand wrist joint, in depth image using kinect?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mapping, kinect

I captured a depth image of a human body in the room and I collected and saved Skeletal data related to that depth image (the joints of wrists, elbows, ...).
[Considering the joints' coordinates are in the camera space and depth image is in depth space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/kinect/dn785530(v=ieb.10)), I was able to show the location of the right hand wrist joint on depth image using this code:

```
depthJointIndices = metadata.DepthJointIndices(:, :, trackedBodies);
plot(depthJointIndices(11,1), depthJointIndices(11,2), '*');
```

Now I want to know which pixel EXACTLY contains the right hand wrist joint, how can I do this properly?
I thought that I can get the coordinate of `x,y` of that joint using the code I used to show the right hand wrist joint.
As follows:

```
depthJointIndices = metadata.DepthJointIndices(:, :, trackedBodies);
x=depthJointIndices(11, 1)
y=depthJointIndices(11, 2)
```

But `x,y` are calculated as follows:

```
x = 303.5220

y = 185.6131
```

As you can see `x,y` are Floating-point numbers, but coordinates of pixels can't be Floating-point numbers.
So can anyone help me with this problem? how can I get coordinate of a pixel that is containing  right hand wrist joint, in depth image, using kinect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following 2 equations to derive the coordinates.

[image: xCoordinate]

[image: yCoordinate]

Here,

> (U,V) and Z denote screen coordinates and depth value, respectively, Cx and Cy denote the center of a depth map, and fx and fy are the focal lengths of the camera. For Kinect-V1 cameras, fx = fy = 580

You can refer the paper [Action Recognition From Depth Maps Using Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7358110) by P. Wang et.al for more information.

Comment: Not exactly. You can roundoff the answer to the nearest integer. I have used this formula to get the value of z of a pixel and it worked for me.

Comment: But that was the question, could you please check if you can help her on this detail?